# Ajax filtering not working in CGridView in Yii (also the advanced search form does not open on clicking 'Advanced Search')

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have just started to work on Yii and facing some issues on CGridView..

the ajax filter is not working in the grid view.. when i chceked the console i see that no ajax request is sent.

this is my view (admin.php)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#user-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'email_id',
    'name',
    'user_type',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

model file(User.php)

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('email_id',$this->email_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    //$criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('user_type',$this->user_type);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                     'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>3),
    ));
}
```

and inside rules()

```
 array('id, email_id, name,  user_type', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

in controller file (UserController.php)

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new User('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['User']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Also advanced search form does not open on clicking 'Advanced Search'..
I have searched a number of threads related to it but its not helping..
pls help me in identifying the problem..
Regards Leo

Comment: Are you sure you don't receive a JavaScript error?

Comment: i am getting this error not sure its related to it : uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null

Comment: Is it JS error? Because to me it looks like filtering is not working because JavaScript is not being executed & JavaScript is not being executed because you have a JS error. So if you're a getting a JS error you should try to find that component gives it & fix it. After that the search should start to work.

Comment: you are probably right...i will try to fix it first :)

Comment: yes it was indeed js error...thanks for your help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unreproducible JavaScript error that was not related to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

Debuging tip: If something depending on the JavaScript is not working, 99% you're getting a JavaScript error which terminates the rest of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error some time ago.
It was because I had included my own jquery declaration at the bottom of my page
and there was a conflict with YII auto script management, that includes jquery declaration in the head
of the page.

You should be able to see that by looking at the generated source code of your page...

Good luck